# Java DateTimeFormatter Not Working for Pattern 'ddMyyyy'

Tags: java, date, datetime, parsing, text-parsing

Consider the following date:

```java
String date = "2391995";
String patt = "ddMyyyy";
```

Using the pattern provided, we can see that `date` represents September 23, 1995.

But consider what happens when trying to parse it - first the old way, and then the Java 8+ way:

```java
Date dd = new SimpleDateFormat(patt).parse(date);
System.out.println(dd);
        
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(patt);
LocalDate d = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
System.out.println(d);
```

Output:

```java
Sat Sep 23 00:00:00 EDT 1995
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2391995' could not be parsed at index 7
    ...
```

As we can see, the old way, using `SimpleDateFormat` works as intended. But when using `DateTimeFormatter` and `LocalDate.parse`, an error occurs. Why is this?

Comment: What about 1102023 (1 Oct 2023)? I think you will need 'ddMMyyyy', for 'ddMyyyy'  may not be a valid date format.

Comment: @cliff2310 that case in particular I believe I see a way around (there's no zero month, so 110 has to refer to 10/1), but I think I see your point if we consider something like 1112023 (111 is ambiguous, and could refer to 11-1 or 1-11). Unfortunately, I have no control over the format

Comment: First, you obviously cannot represent all the months of the year that way. That may be OK if it’s for a special purpose. Second I believe that you can use a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` to specify 1-digit month and that way build a `DateTimeFormatter` that can parse into a `LocalDate`.

Comment: @OleV.V …of course you can’t represent all months of the year with 1 digit, `M` historically refers to a month without zero padding (8, 9, 10 instead of 08, 09, 10)

Comment: An interesting error; the month should be discernible from the `dd`, as opposed to a single `d`.

Comment: It looks like _[DateTimeFormatterBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) would be the solution, since you'll have more control over each pattern character.

Comment: So are you saying that you want for example 31121995? So 7 digits in total during the first 9 months of the year and 8 digits for October through December? (That would be a further complication compared to what I understood from the question. Also `SimpleDateFormat` would not be able to do that, and I don’t think that `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` would either.)

Comment: [Here’s a `DateTimeFormatter` that accepts both ddMuuuu and ddMMuuuu, running onlinne](https://rextester.com/PTJID8297). I simply specified each of them as optional and used `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendValue(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 1)` to specify 1-digit month.

Comment: One of the big problems with `SimpleDateFormat` was it also "worked" for for example `23111995`, only if you expected 23 November 1995, no such luck. You get `Mon Jan 23 00:00:00 CET 11995`, nearly 10000 years off.

Answer (score 7):

The reason the pattern  `ddMyyyy` works with `SimpleDateFormat` but not with `DateTimeFormatter` is due to the differences in pattern symbols and their interpretation between these two classes.

`SimpleDateFormat` and `DateTimeFormatter` are used to parse and format dates, but they have different sets of pattern symbols and behaviors.

In `SimpleDateFormat`, the `M` pattern symbol represents the month in numeric form, and it is intended to handle both single and double-digit months. So, in your original pattern `ddMyyyy`, the `M` symbol was interpreted as a single-digit month, and that's why it worked with the input `"2391995"` (assuming it's meant to be `"23/9/1995"`).

On the other hand, in `DateTimeFormatter`, the `M` pattern symbol is specifically intended for parsing single or double-digit months, but it requires a month value that includes a leading zero for single-digit months. Since your input `"2391995"` has a single-digit month (9), it does not have a leading zero, and that's why the pattern `ddMyyyy` didn't work as expected.

Like I said, to solve you can include a leading zero, but you can also split the values this way:

```java
String date = "23 9 1995";
String patt = "dd M yyyy";
```

Check this out:

- [*Java SimpleDateFormat Patterns*](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-simpledateformat)
- [*Java DateTimeFormatter Patterns*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns)

Comment: Hi, so if I'm not mistaken, you're saying that only the zero padded month (`MM`) works in `DateTimeFormatter`, and not the padding-free month (`M`) like in `SimpleDateFormat`? Thanks

Comment: Exactly. But you can also split the `date` and `patt`, this way: `String date = "23 9 1995"` & `String patt = "dd M yyyy"`. I will put this in my answer.

Comment: but not for formatting - using `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMyyyy")` when formatting will result in `1882023` for example

Comment: @DiegoBorba, do you have a reference for this?  I can't find it in the _JavaDoc_.

Comment: @Reilas I put in the answer the links that I thought be most pertinent, but i research mainly in [Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/)

Comment: Where in the DateTimeFormatter javadoc does it state that M can only be parsed as two digits?

Comment: @DiegoBorba, no I mean where it says that the `M` cannot be singular for parsing.

Comment: But i said *"the M pattern symbol is specifically intended for parsing single or double-digit months"*.

Comment: BTW `LocalDate.parse("7 0009 1822", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d M y"))` results in `1822-09-07`

Comment: For numerical fields a single letter means "as many digits as it takes" (so as you said it does not mean "1 digit"). Unfortunately this is not well documented. And unfortunately for months it is not limited to two digits. It accept `009` for September too, for example, which does not really make sense to me.